# How to use @{username} in comments correctly?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

When I begin my comment with @{username}, it is removed from the comment text. What is the right syntax to use @{username} in comments?

Comment: You're trying to `@`-ping the post author? While nobody else has contributed to the comments? Then the ping is removed because the post author is notified of the comment anyway, and it doesn't add any valuable information, since your comment could be in reply to nobody else.

Comment: Thank you for your response! No, to to ping, but just to mark, that this user is the addressee of my comment. But I actually cannot find a SO-question with multiple comments authors, where I had this problem. But: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832546/how-to-use-the-global-php-local-php-configs-in-the-getconfig-of-a-module-in-a#comment22539701_15833073) -- I could not address Sam in my comments, but some Sam's comments begins with @automatix. How is it possible?

Comment: That's just the scenario I described. Sam is the author of the answer under which these comments are. So he is automatically notified of any new comment there. Nobody but Sam and you participated in the comments there, so it's clear that you are addressing him. Thus there's no need to mark that with an `@`. If you want to make it explicit nevertheless, use just "Sam, ..." instead of `@Sam`. If somebody else would have posted a comment there in between, you would be able to use `@Sam`.

Comment: @DanielFischer What you say is true, but these points are not addressed in the question that this was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: @automatix anyway, if you want to address someone and it turns out the system removes your @ ping, just edit the comment and put the name in without @...

Comment: @MrLister Point 10 in the answer says an `@name` will be removed "from the beginning of the comment" under these circumstances. But, reading that, it may not be removed if _not at the beginning of the comment_, might be worth a try.

Comment: @Daniel Got it! :)